# jQuery Scrollable Pagination

Tags: jquery, pagination

I just wanted to know if somebody knows some jQuery scripts that do some effect like this one:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/05/23/fresh-sliding-thumbnails-gallery-with-jquery-php/

I mean the scrolling thumbs. as I'm developing a website with pagination and when it comes to style I don't want that multi-line pagination links.
I want it to fit the width of its container.

I came across some scripts that do like that:
prev 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... 23 next

I don't want this but I want a list that scrolls on hovering each side and that is SEO friendly.

the demo I showed you is what I want but the problem is that the code is not clear since it has many other functions related to the photo gallery.

Please help me get the simplest code for a simple <ul>

Thank You in Advance!

Comment: Questions on SO should show the code you've tried, not be just a general request for solutions. See http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google "jquery scrollers". You might find this useful:

[jQuery Smooth Div Scroll by Thomas Kahn - smooth content scrolling using jQuery](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/)